# Spring Boot Admin : java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

This is the error, i am getting collected from the spring boot log.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

Also, Now not able to see any application in spring boot admin page, only the spring boot admin as service is running.

Also, I have seen few question relate to broken pipe but they are not anywhere close to my question.

Help if anyone knows what to do.

Comment: I find out one answer in github they were saying just enable the debug mode.. nothing mush.. any other help

Comment: Could you share us your code?

Answer (score 3):

This exception caused due to many reasons like when response is not received by Client for any request and connection closed due to any reason Or once request is created but anyhow that request is canceled by client .

So in this case you can't do anything just handle it in controlleradvice then return some proper message with required status code. 
 Hope it helps you.